# Unable to delete configuration with id ADAPTER_CONTENT due to exception FWLSE3208E: An invalid status code "404" was returned

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

We are trying deploy http adapter in mfp 8.0.0.0.210710251725 and got following error. we are using WAS ND 8.5.5.12 and follows mfp asymmetric deployment topology.

```
[1/11/17 23:20:44:221 IST] 000001b0 ConfigService E com.ibm.worklight.admin.configservice.datastore.ConfigServiceClient deleteConfiguration Unable to delete configuration with id ADAPTER_CONTENT due to exception FWLSE3208E: An invalid status code "404" was returned. The response content is "{"reason":"configuration_not_found","details":"CNFSRVE115: configuration with id 'ADAPTER_CONTENT' for schema 'mfp_default_schema' with version '1.0' not found"}".
[1/11/17 23:20:44:241 IST] 000001b6 BaseTransacti E   RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception
                             java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminClientImpl.invoke(AdminClientImpl.java:224)
at com.worklight.common.util.jmx.WASRuntimeMBeanHandler$AdminClientMBeanServerConnection.invoke(WASRuntimeMBeanHandler.java:633)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$InvokeHandler.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:179)
at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:269)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.sync(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.BaseCommitable.syncMBean(BaseCommitable.java:512)
at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:82)
at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:44)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:ServerException; msg=The Soap RPC call can&apos;t be unmarshalled.]
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.handleAdminFault(SOAPConnectorClient.java:966)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplateOnce(SOAPConnectorClient.java:931)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:696)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:686)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:672)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:494)
... 14 more
```

any solution?

Comment: Please provide some more detail.

Comment: what details required ?

Comment: @PavanGugale Are you able to build the adapter ?

Comment: @PavanGugale Also make sure if you server is running or not where you are deploying the Adapter.

Comment: please try this:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22012346

`com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.disableSOAPAuthCheck = true`